# computer wakes up without any reason

Tags: windows, windows-vista, sleep

Sometimes my PC wakes up (from sleep mode) without any visible reason. Wake-on-LAN is turned off. Vista 64 bit SP2
Any ideas?

Comment: The same thing happened to me. I suspect the PSU had something to do with it...

Comment: give it some warm milk, and sing it a lullaby ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a problem with the mouse. Sometimes optical mice generate fake "move" events, even though mouse doesn't move actually. Disabling waking up by mouse solved this problem.

Answer (score 3):

In an elevated command prompt, run the command "powercfg -energy". It will run for a minute and produce a report of the power configuration of your computer, including all events that can bring it out of sleep mode.

Also in an elevated command prompt, run "powercfg -lastwake". It should tell you which event or device brought it out of sleep mode the last time.

Comment: "powercfg -energy" - says Invalid Parameters :-/  "powercfg -lastwake" - says "Wake Source Count - 0". Something completely meaningless.

Comment: Oups, "-energy" is Windows 7 only. But the other one "-lastwake" is supported in Vista.

Comment: It doesn't help anyway. See above. Any ideas why it shows such strange message?

Answer (score 2):

1. Click Start, right click Computer and choose Properties.
2. Click Device Manager.
3. Navigate to your network adapter, right click it and choose Properties.
4. Choose Power Management tab.
5. Please uncheck “Allow this device to wake the computer”
6. Restart the computer and test this issue again.

**[EDIT]**

(check for other devices too who had that option enabled)

Comment: What "this" device? :-/

Comment: the network adapter ...

Comment: Already unchecked :-/

Comment: Do you have more than one network adapter listed?

Comment: Who marked this down? It's a perfectly valid explanation to this problem, even if it doesn't solve this particular case. +1

Comment: "Perfectly valid" answer to the question that wasn't asked.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any bluetooth devices paired and active while the machine is asleep? My bluetooth mouse will wake my computer from time to time.

Comment: I have a bluetooth mouse. Any additional info on this problem?

Comment: Might want to re-install the driver.

Comment: I use a Macbook, so not sure about Vista, but if I leave my bluetooth mouse switched on, the slightest movement will try to wake the thing. The problem goes away if I switch the mouse off.

Answer (score 0):

I once had two PCs in one room. One was setup (in BIOS) to start on left mouse klick. That PC started completely randomly. After a few days I noticed it was the mouse. Both PCs had wireless mice, and for some reason, both mice were setup for the same channel. So the 2nd PC started, when I clicked the mouse button on my PC.

Maybe its a similar problem with your setup?